# new to java... "using the time and date as an int?"

Tags: java, date, time, int

I have recently started learning java for creating android apps.   I have spent hours and hours looking for the right code to be able to use the current time and date as an int.   I'm sure it's very easy but I can't seem to find the correct coding.   My first app im creating it will be crucial for a number to increase with time.   Thank you for your help!

Chris

Comment: do you want the full date, as in, 01032012 for March 2nd of 2012 or just the date 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it as a `long`, see javadocs:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()

But why would you do it, that's another question... Choose wisely :) Nothing wrong with having dates represented as numbers per se, but any calculations are bound to hit some of the numerous corner cases - you might want to look at this SOq for one really mind-boggling examples:

- [Why is subtracting these two times (in 1927) giving a strange result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result/6841479#6841479)

and this SOq for a bunch of best practices:

- [Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices)

If you are interested in any date calculations, you may want to look at Joda Time library:

- http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

I'd say that when you have such good and well tested libraries readily available, it's rarely a good idea to go your own way.

Comment: I am honestly VERY new to the java language... Creating this app is my way of learning the language. I'm creating an app for cars and I need to be able to update the entered odometer reading by the average set miles driven. I don't want to ask really how to do everything unless there might be a simple answer to my question. Thank you for the fast response!

Comment: Sure thing - `getTime` method on a date object will get you what you want - to quote the docs: "Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object.".

Comment: So far I have been able to find tutorials to help me learn all the information I need, alot of "youtube" and "TheNewBoston" I guess I am concerned that I learn it the simplest way and the right way.   And by new to the java language I have been studying it for only 3 months now on my own time as a hobby.

Comment: Actually one of the easiest is to get System.getCurrentTimeinMillis() if you don't mind getting the time as a long. You can then always pass that to either java.util.Date or java.util.GregorianCalendar as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid the Date class and use GregorianCalendar instead.  It has built-in arithmetic functions, and if you *really* need it, there's a getTimeInMillis() method.